# Aggregate sum on two columns in the same table

Tags: sql-server, union, aggregate-functions, data-partitioning

I am querying a data warehouse (so I cannot redesign tables), I'll do my best to mimic the scenario in a simple example.

We have 3 main tables for incident, change, and release. These 3 are connected through an intermediate table called intermediate. Here is their structure along with sample data:

**Incident Table:**

[image]

**Change Table:**

[image]

**Release Table:**

[image]

**Intermediate Table:**

[image]

The first 3 tables have exact same structure, but the intermediate table holds connection of these 3 tables pairwise. For example, if Rel1 is connected to Chg1, you have a row in the intermediate table as  or . These two rows have no difference and may not co-exist.

**QUERY:**

I want ALL release records along with number of related incidents and number of related changes. Here is how I achieved this:

```
 WITH SourceTable AS(
SELECT R.ReleaseItem, R.Prop1, R.Prop2 , I.RelOrInc2 as [RelatedIncident] , Null as [RelatedChanges] FROM Release R
    LEFT JOIN [Intermediate] I
    ON R.ReleaseItem = I.RelOrInc1
    WHERE SUBSTRING(I.RelOrInc2,1,3) = 'Inc'
UNION

SELECT R.ReleaseItem, R.Prop1, R.Prop2 , I.RelOrInc1 , Null as [RelatedChanges] FROM Release R
    LEFT JOIN [Intermediate] I
    ON R.ReleaseItem = I.RelOrInc2
    WHERE SUBSTRING(I.RelOrInc1,1,3) = 'Inc'

UNION

SELECT R.ReleaseItem, R.Prop1, R.Prop2 , Null as [RelatedIncident] , I.RelOrInc2 as [RelatedChanges] FROM Release R
    LEFT JOIN [Intermediate] I
    ON R.ReleaseItem = I.RelOrInc1
    WHERE SUBSTRING(I.RelOrInc2,1,3) = 'Chg'
UNION

SELECT R.ReleaseItem, R.Prop1, R.Prop2 , Null as [RelatedIncident] , I.RelOrInc1  as [RelatedChanges] FROM Release R
    LEFT JOIN [Intermediate] I
    ON R.ReleaseItem = I.RelOrInc2
    WHERE SUBSTRING(I.RelOrInc1,1,3) = 'Chg'
    ) 

SELECT REL.* , COUNT(S.RelatedIncident) As [No Of Related Incidents] , COUNT(S.[RelatedChanges]) AS [No of Related Changes] FROM Release REL 
    LEFT JOIN SourceTable S
    ON REL.ReleaseItem = S.ReleaseItem
GROUP BY REL.ReleaseItem, REL.Prop1, REL.Prop2
```

This query gives me my required result:

[image]

But I think my way of handling this query is so naive and not efficient. My data warehouse may contain around millions of records in intermediate table and my approach could be too slow.

**Question:**
Is there any better way to get such result with better performance?

BTW, I am using MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   
  R.ReleaseItem, R.Prop1, R.Prop2,
  [No Of Related Incidents] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Intermediate] i 
         WHERE (i.RelOrInc1 = r.ReleaseItem AND i.RelOrInc2 LIKE 'Inc%') 
         OR (i.RelOrInc2 = r.ReleaseItem AND i.RelOrInc1 LIKE 'Inc%')),
  [No of Related Changes] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Intermediate] i 
         WHERE (i.RelOrInc1 = r.ReleaseItem AND i.RelOrInc2 LIKE 'Chg%') 
         OR (i.RelOrInc2 = r.ReleaseItem AND i.RelOrInc1 LIKE 'Chg%'))
FROM Release R
```

Comment: Is this notation working on all version of MS SQL Server, I mean [Column Alias] = (Some Query). Your query is very clear and concise. Thanks

Comment: @YasserSobhdel, glad to help. Yes, it supported by all version of SQL server, at least SQL Server 2005 and above.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you. Can not say anything about performance. You should check.

```
select r.releaseitem, 
       r.prop1,
       r.prop2,
       sum(case when t.relorinc2 like 'inc%' then 1 else 0 end) as incidents,
       sum(case when t.relorinc2 like 'chg%' then 1 else 0 end) as changes     
from (select relorinc1, relorinc2 from intermediate where relorinc1 like 'rel%'
      union all
      select relorinc2, relorinc1 from intermediate where relorinc2 like 'rel%')t
join release r on t.relorinc1 = r.releaseitem
group by r.releaseitem, r.prop1, r.prop2
```

Comment: Thank you, I think the other post is more simple and hence I mark that as answer.